# jQuery Cycle Plugin stop on first slide after first loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, slider, cycle

I'm trying to play my slideshow through once + 1. In order to acheive this I've set my options to play the slideshow once, then after it ends, to resume to the first slide, then stop.

I feel like my code should work, and it mostly does. The slideshow plays through all the slides and then continues to animate to the first slide again, with one caveat: The slide pager 'active' item isn't updating along with the slideshow. For some reason the last item is the one that remains active.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$('.slides_container').after('<div id="slides-nav" class="pagination">').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollLeft',
    // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    pause: true,
    pager: '#slides-nav',
    speed: 500,
    timeout: 500,
    autostop: true,
    end: function(options) {  
        $('.slides_container').cycle('resume').cycle('0').cycle('stop');  
    }
});
```

I've set the speed and timeout to 500 just for easy testing.

Edit - Great. I've created a jsfiddle to demonstrate. But it doesn't even work the same as the one in my actual project. [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/norsewulf/TnLYq/157/) doesn't seem to be looping at all once the slideshow ends. So much for that...

One way or another my problem still remains. Feel free to use the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/norsewulf/TnLYq/157/) to help me out.

Comment: You may want to put up together an [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to get some answers

Comment: @Alexander - Thanks I created a fiddle. Though it's not working the same as the plugin in my actual project, which is disappointing. However the problem remains the same one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! In my case I had to count the immediate child `div` elements because I was using background images. But for the sake of demonstration, in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/norsewulf/TnLYq/172/) we're looking for `img` elements instead.

As you can see we've just counted the number of immediate children and added 1 to the count, then defined that as our `autostopCount` option.

`autostopCount: $('#banner > img').length+1`